# Reading parameter from community URL

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, community, url

Is there any way to direct read the param from the community URL.
For example I have a custom page with URL like https://abc.com/s/testing?testingAttribute=abc
and I want to get the passed testingAttribute attribute and pass the same to the flow added in that community page.

Using lightning:isUrlAddressable I can set the value :
var pageReference = {
                type: 'type to do',
                attributes: {
                    componentName: 'c__helloTarget',
                },
                state: {
                    "c__firstname": "John"
                }
            };
            component.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);

and get the same in other component like `var myPageRef = cmp.get("v.pageReference");

However when i am trying to access the values directly Its not working.On the JS side I am using like this :

```
({
    init : function (component) {

        // Find the component whose aura:id is "flowId"
        var flow = component.find("flowId");
        // In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow's Unique Name.
        flow.startFlow("flowname");
       console.log(component.get("v.pageReference").state.testAttribute);

    },
```

Getting the below error on running :
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://2o7.net/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use design time attributes to bind the query string parameters to your component. Define these in your component's `.design` file.

```
<design:component>
    <design:attribute name="myAttribute" default="{!myAttribute}" description="Automatically bind the url parameter to the component variable" />
</design:component>
```

You will need a corresponding attribute in your component's `.cmp` file.

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="myAttribute" type="String" access="global" />

    {!v.myAttribute}
</aura:component>
```

**Important:** You must remove and re-add your component onto the community page, then publish the site for new attributes to take effects.

Comment: Need to have attribute marked as global

Comment: Thanks @sdfc-neta. Have updated the answer with the global modifier.